# How to use decorater instead of assignment?

Tags: python

I'm working on a python project where I need to collect statistics about requests that are being made.
Is there a way to use a decorator to wrap `requests.get` instead of assigning it to a function value?
This is the current working code using assignment. It feels like it should be made with decorator:

```
import requests

reff = requests.get

def wrapget(*args, **kwargs):
    result = reff(*args, **kwargs)
    print(result.status_code)
    return result

requests.get = wrapget

res1 = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a decorator in the traditional sense (a function that takes a function and returns a function), but you cannot avoid the reassignment of `requests.get`, because that's what using a decorator does (explicitly or implicitly with the @-syntax).

```
def with_status_print(f):
     def f_with_print(*args, **kwargs):
         result = f(*args, **kwargs):
         print(result.status_code)
         return result
     return f_with_print

requests.get = with_status_print(requests.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither attempting to decorate a function which is already defined nor overwriting a function defined in an external module sound like a good idea (you don't *really* know where it might be used in the entire code base and what side-effects the new behavior is going to have).

I'd just use the wrapping function directly.

```
res1 = wrapped_get('https://www.google.com')
```

Mocking is an entire different story, but it does not look like that's what you are attempting to do here.

Comment: thank you for taking the time and answering, the purpose of the code is to not alter existing code and api, so the implementation of ```res1 = requests.get('https://www.google.com')``` will not break and will print the status code

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same thing using a decorator like this — although I'm not sure there's really much point since you can't use `@` notation to apply it so it doesn't get rid of the explicit assignment:

```
import requests

def wrapper(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(result.status_code)
        return result
    return wrapped

requests.get = wrapper(requests.get)  # Decorate function.

res1 = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
```